# Is it possible to delete chrome history using wildcards?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I know I can highlight individual items in chrome's history and remove them, using chrome:history, but I'd like to delete all entries from a given domain, and all entries matching a given set of search criteria.  How would I do that?  Is there an extension that gives this?

Comment: A [better answer](http://superuser.com/a/484721/61808) had been added and the selected answer should be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is currently no way to efficiently remove multiple entries from the history, however I have submitted an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76125) to request a way to remove multiple entries via wildcard and/or date range. Time will tell if they ever bother to implement it.

Answer (score 8):

Get the [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb#detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb) extension, it does all that.

Comment: That extension rules.

Answer (score 7):

1. Do your search like normal
2. Click on "Edit Items"
3. To delete all of the entries for that screen, check the first item you want to delete and scroll to the bottom. Now hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on your keyboard and click the last item shown. All items are now checked and you can remove individual items as you see fit.
4. Now click "Remove selected"
5. Click "Older" at the bottom of the page
6. Repeat steps 3-4
7. Click on "Done removing items"

Source: [Google Groups](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vj0ML01G7aM)